# Firebase how to enable save prompt for currentuser?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

i am using firebase authentication. When i login to the app, it's giving this error:

W/SmartLockViewModel: Non-resolvable exception: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16: The save prompt is disabled for the current app. To restore, remove this app from the "Never save" list in the Smart Lock for Passwords settings for all accounts on this device.

How can solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem. I just had to add  `.setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)` in my firebase authentication in android.